# Editing a theme form, having difficulty

Tags: html, css, forms

```html
></div>
<p> </p>
<div></div>
<form method="post" class="contact-form" action="/contact" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input value="contact" name="form_type" type="hidden" />
  <input value="✓" name="utf8" type="hidden" />
  <h3>Drop us a line</h3>
  <div class="krown-column-container span4 first">
    <label class="hidden-label" for="contactFormName">Name</label>
    <input value="" autocapitalize="words" placeholder="Name" name="contact[name]" id="contactFormName" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="krown-column-container span4">
    <label class="hidden-label" for="contactFormEmail">Email</label>
    <input value="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Email" name="contact[email]" id="contactFormEmail" type="email" />
  </div>
  <div class="krown-column-container span4">
    <label class="hidden-label" for="contactFormPhone">Phone Number</label>
    <input value="" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Phone Number" name="contact[phone]" id="contactFormPhone" type="tel" />
  </div>
  <div class="krown-column-container span12 first">
    <label class="hidden-label" for="contactFormMessage">Message</label>
    <textarea placeholder="Message" name="contact[body]" id="contactFormMessage" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
  <input value="Submit" class="button color" type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have a form from a theme that I want to tweak a little. I want to change the background field so that it has a colour (not plain white as is now). I also want to set it up so It goes to one of my emails once the form has been filled in. I find it easy to do all this in the inspect element in the browser but can't do it in the editor.

I have the html code for it here.

```
    > </div>
<p> </p>
<div></div>
<form method="post" class="contact-form" action="/contact" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input value="contact" name="form_type" type="hidden" /><input value="✓" name="utf8" type="hidden" />
<h3>Drop us a line</h3>
<div class="krown-column-container span4 first"><label class="hidden-label" for="contactFormName">Name</label> <input value="" autocapitalize="words" placeholder="Name" name="contact[name]" id="contactFormName" type="text" /></div>
<div class="krown-column-container span4"><label class="hidden-label" for="contactFormEmail">Email</label> <input value="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Email" name="contact[email]" id="contactFormEmail" type="email" /></div>
<div class="krown-column-container span4"><label class="hidden-label" for="contactFormPhone">Phone Number</label> <input value="" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Phone Number" name="contact[phone]" id="contactFormPhone" type="tel" /></div>
<div class="krown-column-container span12 first"><label class="hidden-label" for="contactFormMessage">Message</label> <textarea placeholder="Message" name="contact[body]" id="contactFormMessage" rows="10"></textarea></div>
<br style="clear: left;" /> <input value="Submit" class="button color" type="submit" /></form>
```

Comment: Could you make jsFiddle for this problem? That way it would be much easier for people to see what the problem is.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context: is it just a plain HTML + CSS theme? Is it for WordPress or some similar tool? You can insert relevant code parts for things you want to change or need help with. You can also use a site like JSFiddle to share a snippet.

Comment: The HTML you provided seems to be incomplete. Can you check it? And post the CSS you have as well.

Comment: Sorry this website is always seeming a mystery to me! I think I have managed to post the relevant information now. The site in question is https://willsperkins.myshopify.com/. The page witht he form is the contact us page.

Comment: what you want to do..?

Comment: I have a form from a theme that I want to tweak a little. I want to change the background field so that it has a colour (not plain white as is now). I also want to set it up so It goes to one of my emails once the form has been filled in. I find it easy to do all this in the inspect element in the browser but can't do it in the editor.